# How to build networking layer suitable for testing using Alamofire and Dependency Injection?

Tags: ios, swift, networking, alamofire

So, I have been trying to build a networking layer that can be easy to use, maintain and test. I decide to go with Alamofire since it is really easy to use, and easyto maintain (specially when using Routing).

But I have been stuck at the test part. Here is why: how can I inject the base API url to a router? Should I use something else instead of the routing pattern?

Below I will leave a UML diagram and portions of the code.
[image: UML diagram]

```
public protocol Router: URLRequestConvertible {
    var path: String { get }
    var method: HTTPMethod { get }
    var parameters: Parameters { get }
}

// this extension will provide a default implementation
// of the asURLRequest function
extension Router {
    public func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
        // my problem begins here, since I am using
        // a static/global reference for the base url
        let url = try BASE_URL.asURL()
        let request = try URLRequest(url: url.appendingPathComponent(path), method: method)
        guard !parameters.isEmpty else { return request }

        return try JSONEncoding.default.encode(request, with: parameters)
    }
}
```

Thank you so much for your time and help.

Comment: Just make BASE_URL as a variable then set mock URL for it. Or you could define a function in Router protocol to get BaseURL. Then make a default implementation for it

Comment: But, one cannot have stored properties in `enum`. About the function, the same question remains, because the default implementation, where will take the value from somewhere (like reading a config file for example), but in my case, I would like for this to be injectable. @HuyNguyễn

Comment: You mean BASE_URL is enum? You can use singleton as DI implicitly. Some guys in Kickstarter have a great articles about DI of whole application. You should take a look at https://github.com/pointfreeco/episode-code-samples/blob/master/0018-environment-pt2/Environment.playground/Contents.swift